# How can i add a column in SQL and set its values based on other columns at the same time in a single query?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

For example, I have a `Student` table with columns named: `id`, `name`, `marks_obtained`, `total_marks`, etc.

I want to add a column named `percentage` whose values will be equal to (`marks_obtained`/`total_marks`)*100.

How can I do the whole thing in a single query?

Comment: Don't add a column to you table, create a view with the percentage column (always fresh). Storing calculated data is a bit dangerous, data inconsistency you know. (If you really, really need to add the column to your table, use triggers to ensure data consistency.)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: If you're using MySQL then 
as of MySQL 5.7 you can supposedly have calculated columns. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-generated-columns. If you're using Oracle see either answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 11g (since this is tagged Oracle) you can use a virtual column:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d8038f0/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Student ( id, name, marks_obtained, total_marks ) AS
          SELECT 1, 'Alice',  90, 100 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Bob',    72, 100 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Claire', 93, 105 FROM DUAL;

ALTER TABLE Student ADD (
  percentage NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( marks_obtained * 100 / total_marks ) VIRTUAL
);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM Student
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d8038f0/1/0)**:

```
| ID |   NAME | MARKS_OBTAINED | TOTAL_MARKS |        PERCENTAGE |
|----|--------|----------------|-------------|-------------------|
|  1 |  Alice |             90 |         100 |                90 |
|  2 |    Bob |             72 |         100 |                72 |
|  3 | Claire |             93 |         105 | 88.57142857142857 |
```

Comment: MySQL version 5.7.4 or later also allows you to add "generated" columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add a computed column to the table you can do the calculation in the SQL which fetches your data, e.g.:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       marks_obtained,
       total_marks,
       (marks_obtained / total_marks) * 100 AS PERCENTAGE
  FROM STUDENT
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3abb69/2)

Best of luck.